# How to make GWT DatePicker to use Monday as the first day of the week?

Tags: gwt, date, datepicker

Pretty much, what the title says. I need to make the GWT DatePicker component use Monday as the first day of the week. Currently the day labels are `S M T W T F S`, I want it to be `M T W T F S S`. Any way to accomplish it?

Comment: I think this DatePicker is using you locale to automatically customize DatePicker for you. http://code.google.com/p/gwt-datepicker/wiki/HowToUse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the automatic locale detection doesn't fit your needs (and probably editing the `firstDayOfTheWeek` in `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.constants.DateTimeConstantsImpl_xy.properties` won't be either), the only option would be to modify the implementation of DatePicker:

- Extend DatePicker, write a new constructor which calls the protected `DatePicker(MonthSelector monthSelector, CalendarView view, CalendarModel model)` constructor with your own view and model.
- The CalendarModel can be extended, so you'd have to override `getCurrentFirstDayOfFirstWeek`.
- The `DefaultCalendarView` is final, so you'd have to copy it to a new class and modify its `setup` method.

It's quite messy, and that's the little downside of GWT - it makes heavy use of Singletons instead of Dependency Injection...

Comment: Mmmm... I'm gonna accept this as an answer, because I was thinking the same thing. I'm gonna try it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't need to subclass the DatePicker. Please read the google gwt documentation by clicking below url.
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html#LocaleSpecifying

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code of [DefaultCalendarView](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DefaultCalendarView.html) (which can be provided in the protected constructor of a [DatePicker](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DatePicker.html)) it uses [CalendarUtil](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.html#getStartingDayOfWeek())'s getStartingDayOfWeek to set the default starting day. `CalendarUtil` gets the start date from `DateTimeConstants`. So, as ju said, it's determined by your locale.

The question is, how do you override the default locale value. To be honest, I don't know how to do this or if it's even possible. That would obviously be the easiest solution.

However, if that's not possible, what you can do is create a class that extends `DatePicker`. Then create another class that extends `DefaultCalendarView` and overrides the `setup` method. Copy over the same method source but change the start date to Monday instead of using the start date from `CalendarUtil`. Then create your custom `DatePicker` using your custom `DefaultCalendarView`. It's a hack, but it should work.

Comment: Specifying a different locale is easy (it's in the [GWT docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html#LocaleSpecifying)) - but then it would apply to every GWT widget in the page... BTW: Did you really basically copy my answer?!

Comment: Hahaha, I started writing mine when there were no answers but I wasn't able to finish it right away. By the time I finished and submitted it, yours was there... for some reason Stackoverflow didn't warn me like it's done before. Sorry :P

Comment: No worries - Happy to find somebody who thinks alike :-)