# Set first day of week in DatePicker to monday

Tags: android, date, calendar, datepicker

I have a DatePicker where I disabled the SpinnerView and now only use the CalendarView. But it starts with the sunday and I would like to use monday as the first day of the week. How can I change that? I guessed that the first day would depend on the phones settings but on my swiss phone its still wrong...

I haven't found any set Method or any XML command.

```
<DatePicker
   android:id="@+id/date_picker"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

and

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)   convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
datePicker.setSpinnersShown(false);
```

**------------EDIT:------------**

I tried to change the locale:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);
```

But that didn't change anything ether. So I read the android-17.android.widget.DatePicker.java where I found out:

```
public DatePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  //...  
  // initialization based on locale
        setCurrentLocale(Locale.getDefault());
  //...
}


 /**
 * Sets the current locale.
 *
 * @param locale The current locale.
 */
private void setCurrentLocale(Locale locale) {
    if (locale.equals(mCurrentLocale)) {
        return;
    }

    mCurrentLocale = locale;

    mTempDate = getCalendarForLocale(mTempDate, locale);
    mMinDate = getCalendarForLocale(mMinDate, locale);
    mMaxDate = getCalendarForLocale(mMaxDate, locale);
    mCurrentDate = getCalendarForLocale(mCurrentDate, locale);

    mNumberOfMonths = mTempDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    mShortMonths = new String[mNumberOfMonths];
    for (int i = 0; i < mNumberOfMonths; i++) {
        mShortMonths[i] = DateUtils.getMonthString(Calendar.JANUARY + i,
                DateUtils.LENGTH_MEDIUM);
    }
}

 /**
 * Gets a calendar for locale bootstrapped with the value of a given calendar.
 *
 * @param oldCalendar The old calendar.
 * @param locale The locale.
 */
private Calendar getCalendarForLocale(Calendar oldCalendar, Locale locale) {
    if (oldCalendar == null) {
        return Calendar.getInstance(locale);
    } else {
        final long currentTimeMillis = oldCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
        newCalendar.setTimeInMillis(currentTimeMillis);
        return newCalendar;
    }
}
```

So why does Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN) not work?!
As you can see above I get the DatePicker from the XML.. is there any mistake?!

Comment: that is supposed to depend on your locale.

Comment: isn't supposed to be 3 spinners, too ? (in which case, the first day of week is not displayed anyway)

Comment: I would prefer the calendar-style so no 3 spinners. what do you mean exactly with locale? you think maybe my phone's localisation isn't correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to set the first day of week manually, for example in onCreate()/onCreateView() of your activity/fragment:

```
date = (DatePicker) value.findViewById(R.id.date);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
    date.setSpinnersShown(false);
    date.setCalendarViewShown(true);
    date.getCalendarView().setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.getInstance().getFirstDayOfWeek());
}
```

The example above uses default locale (Calendar.getInstance() actually does), however you can specify the day manually:

```
date.getCalendarView().setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

Comment: FYI: getCalendarView() requires API 12 not 11. I fixed that by edit.

Answer (score 12):

The currently accepted answer using `getCalendarView()` is deprecated with Material style.

You can however call `setFirstDayOfWeek()` on the `DatePicker` instance. Or in case you're starting a `DatePickerDialog`:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDlg = new DatePickerDialog(...);
datePickerDlg.getDatePicker().setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
datePickerDlg.show();
```

Comment: Requires min api level 21

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the localization of your device.

Take a look here: [How to make GWT DatePicker to use Monday as the first day of the week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508213/how-to-make-gwt-datepicker-to-use-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week)

Comment: Yea, I've already seen this post but its about/with/in (whatever) GWT. I can't implement that in my android app or can I?

Comment: The question is regarding android mobile app not GWT